# how to handle hover css style together with click event using jquery

Tags: jquery, dhtml

What's the correct way to handle the hover and click event so that my styles are correctly applied?  I have a list of panels that change the background colour to red when hovering.  The problem comes as I need to also change the background colour to red when they click on the panel.  This click event needs to persist even when the mouse leaves the panel.  Is this possible?  Many thanks

**Html**

```
<div class="panel">
    ...
</div>
<div class="panel">
    ...
</div>
<div class="panel">
    ...
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.panel {
    background-color: #fff;
}
.panel:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

**Click event**

```
$('.panel').each(function () {
   $(this).click(function () {
     alert("clickedClass");
   });
});
```

**UPDATE**

This works although I can click all panels when I only want to apply the clickedClass to one panel at a time, so it looks like a 'selected' option.  Is this possible?

```
$('.panel').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('clickClass');
});
```

**NEW CSS**

```
.panel {
   background-color: #fff;
}
.panel:hover {
   background-color: red;
}
.clickedClass {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, basically you need to allow a guy to hover and the color changes to `red`, if clicked it should change to `red` while it is clicked (even if the button is clicked and dragged out of the box it should remain red till click is released).

Answer (score 1):

To  keep the background red when leaving the select you should work with a class I would say

Javascript:

```
$('.panel').each(function () {
   $(this).click(function () {
     $(this).addClass('redbg');
   });
});
```

CSS:

```
.panel {
    background-color: #fff;
}
.panel:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
.panel.redbg {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Kudos! You beat me on this one

Comment: You don't need to iterate through .panel, just delegate it directly to the element

Comment: Hehe the iteration is from your own function. You can get rid of it though

Comment: Are you happy with the answer or do you have more questions? If your question is answered please mark it, thanks :)

Comment: see updated question, I've tried this but I've noticed an issue with the suggestion.

Comment: Ok I see, the answer is given by Anton I think

Answer (score 0):

[.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
$('.panel').click(function () {
   $(this).css('background-color','red');
});
```

---

or you can [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

Answer (score 0):

I think I would add an active class to my css:

```
.panel:hover, .active {
    background-color: red;
 }
```

And add that class onclick:

```
$('.panel').click(function () {
   $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use addClass to add the background and siblings() to target other panel and remove active class

```
$('.panel').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings('.panel').removeClass('active')
});
```

Also note that you do not have to iterate through panel with `.each()`, just delegate directly to the selector.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/W4YP6/)

Comment: this seems to work great.  Let me just make sense of it rather than blinding saying it works.  Get back to you tomorrowz!  Many thanks!